# jQuery accordion with animated timeline

Tags: jquery, sass, accordion, timeline

I am working on an jQuery accordion with an animated timeline. It is almost done, but I am stuck with the line / animation on the last element. You can view a working example on: https://tjobtjob.nl/goldstine-sales-en-acquisitie-medewerker/. Please scroll down to the part called 'Sollicitatieprocedure', almost at the bottom.

It works well for all the steps, except for the last one. The last step also shows a line, but I want this line to disappear, so that the last element only has a colored dot.

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery.fn.simpleAccordion = function (options){
    options = $.extend ({start: 0, activeClass: 'active'}, options || {});

    return this.each (
        function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var headers = $this.children('dt');

            headers.next().hide();
            headers.eq(options.start).addClass(options.activeClass).next().show();

            headers.bind ('click',
                function(){
                    var $this = $(this);

                    $this.addClass(options.activeClass)
                    .next().slideDown();

                    $this.siblings('.' + options.activeClass)
                    .removeClass(options.activeClass) 
                    .next().slideUp();
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
$('dl.stappen').simpleAccordion();
```

And this is the (s)CSS part:

```
dl.stappen{
    width: calc(100% - 45px);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px 0 0;
    padding-left: 45px;
    position: relative;

    dt{
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 21px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;

        &:first-of-type{
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        .round{
            position: absolute;
            left: -45px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            background: #eee;
            border: 3px solid #dcae23;
            border-radius: 10px;
            z-index: 100;
        }
    }
    dd{
        font-size: 17px;
        line-height: 26px;
        position: relative;

        p{
            margin-bottom: 15px;

            &:last-child{
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
        }
    }
    &:before{
        background: #dcae23;
        height: calc(100% - 24px);
        width: 3px;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        left: 8px;
        top: 8px;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Update: put it in a pen: https://codepen.io/bureaukamp/pen/ZEGoaQa

Comment: your jquery on your website does not work. Not loaded in correctly, `b950e48fcfd117d6a429f551af01d325.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: Can you please try again? I emptied the cache

Comment: onclick of the last element, just add a new class with modified css to change the height of the `:after{}` `height` and then remove the class when clicking on any other element

Comment: Thanks! Sounds easy, but I am not a star in jQuery... Is it possible for you to alter the jQuery code a bit so that it works?

Comment: but you're already adding & removing classes on click in your code? adding a class and removing a class on click is jQuery basics

Comment: put your code into a runnable stacksnippet or codepen or something similar

Comment: Thanks! I created a pen: https://codepen.io/bureaukamp/pen/ZEGoaQa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in a better way & simple, the `HTML` structure needs to be updated a bit. Here I have wrapped each accordion item in a `.item` div.

In the below, I have updated `html`, `css` & `js` to make it work at any dynamic variation of the content.

```js
jQuery.fn.simpleAccordion = function(options) {
  options = $.extend({
    start: 0,
    activeClass: "active",
    itemClass: "item"
  }, options || {});

  function updateView(activeItem) {
    var otherItems = activeItem.siblings();
    otherItems
      .removeClass(options.activeClass)
      .children('dd').slideUp();

    activeItem
      .addClass(options.activeClass)
      .children('dd').slideDown();

  }

  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    var itemSelector = "." + options.itemClass;
    var items = $(itemSelector, $this);
    updateView(items.eq(options.start));

    $this.on('click', itemSelector + '>dt', function() {
      var activeItem = $(this).closest(itemSelector);
      if (activeItem.hasClass(options.activeClass)) return;
      updateView(activeItem);
    });

  });
};

$("dl.stappen").simpleAccordion();
```

```css
dl.stappen {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}

dl.stappen .item {
  padding-left: 45px;
  position: relative;
}

dl.stappen .item:before {
  background: black;
  width: 3px;
  bottom: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
}

dl.stappen .item:last-of-type:before {
  display: none;
}

dl.stappen .item dt {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

dl.stappen .item dt:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

dl.stappen .item dt .round {
  position: absolute;
  left: -45px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

dl.stappen .item dd {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

dl.stappen .item dd p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

dl.stappen .item dd p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="stappen">
  <div class="item">
    <dt>
      <div class="round"></div>
      Step one
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description.
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <dt>
      <div class="round"></div>
      Step two
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description.
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <dt>
      <div class="round"></div>
      Step three
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description.description.
    </dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful and working perfectly! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi RaviNila, can you point me in the right direction to keep the accordion elements open?  When you open up one element, the other one closes automatically. My client now also wants the ability to keep the previous element(s) open when clicked on another element. I tried to adjust the code, but I can't seem to figure it out. Hopefully you can help me out one more time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This example should get you going. Play with the easings in the css and add them to the `slideUp()` & `slideDown()` too if you like.

This is done simply by adding and removing a class on click...

```
if ($this.text().trim() == "Step three") {
   $(".stappen").addClass("reduce");
} else {
   $(".stappen").removeClass("reduce");
}
```

And using the following CSS

```
dl.stappen:before {
  ....
  transition: height linear 400ms;
}
dl.stappen.reduce::before {
  height: calc(64% - 45px);
}
```

You will have to change the text in the JS and your height in `calc` accordingly.

```js
jQuery.fn.simpleAccordion = function(options) {
  options = $.extend({ start: 0, activeClass: "active" }, options || {});

  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var headers = $this.children("dt");

    headers.next().hide();
    headers
      .eq(options.start)
      .addClass(options.activeClass)
      .next()
      .show();

    headers.bind("click", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.text().trim() == "Step three") {
        $(".stappen").addClass("reduce");
      } else {
        $(".stappen").removeClass("reduce");
      }
      $this
        .addClass(options.activeClass)
        .next()
        .slideDown();

      $this
        .siblings("." + options.activeClass)
        .removeClass(options.activeClass)
        .next()
        .slideUp();
    });
  });
};
$("dl.stappen").simpleAccordion();
```

```css
dl.stappen {
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding-left: 45px;
  position: relative;
}
dl.stappen dt {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
dl.stappen dt:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
dl.stappen dt .round {
  position: absolute;
  left: -45px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}
dl.stappen dd {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 26px;
  position: relative;
}
dl.stappen dd p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
dl.stappen dd p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
dl.stappen:before {
  background: black;
  height: calc(100% - 24px);
  width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  transition: height linear 400ms;
}
dl.stappen.reduce::before {
  height: calc(64% - 45px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="stappen">
  <dt>
    <div class="round"></div>
    Step one
  </dt>

  <dd>
    Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description. Step one description.
  </dd>

  <dt>
    <div class="round"></div>
    Step two
  </dt>

  <dd>
    Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description. Step two description.
  </dd>

  <dt>
    <div class="round"></div>
    Step three
  </dt>

  <dd>
    Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description. Step three description.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks! Coming close, but two potential problems: (1) the text 'step three' is dynamic and (2) the description is also dynamic, so setting a fixed height unfortunately won't work, only in the instance.

Comment: so then calculate the height...?  This is a different problem to your original question, which I have answered and is working